# looping a curl data using php

Tags: php, json, loops, curl

need your help... how can I convert it on looping:

```
//first
    $url1="https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats";
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    $info1 = curl_getinfo($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);

    $chats1 = json_decode($output1,true);
```

for example there's a specific number count to loop like 4 or more numbers...
then i would like to get all the `$chats`... and merge..

like this:

```
$merge_array = array_merge_recursive($chats1, $chats2, $chats3, $chats4);
```

hope you can help me guy's thanks...

Comment: just run a for loop, what is error you got?

Comment: @HuyTrịnh I tried it on while loop cause there's a count value.. then when i try to merge it.. it turn to array and not working...

Comment: You could run them in parallel rather than in a loop - http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
$chats = [];
for($i=1; $i<= $n; $i++){
    $url1="https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats";
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output1 = curl_exec($ch1);
    $info1 = curl_getinfo($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);

    $chats[] = json_decode($output1,true);
}
$merge_array = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $chats);
echo json_encode($merge_array);
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @ParantapParashar
how can i make it like this bro...
$merge_array = array_merge_recursive($chats1, $chats2, $chats3, $chats4);

Comment: $merge_array = array_merge_recursive($varialbleName); inside of loop or outside?..

Comment: i only get one json when i declare it on the outside of looping and when on inside the looping the json is not merging

Comment: can you update your answer?.. I also trying to convert `$merge_array` to json

Comment: Thanks @ParantapParashar, is there also a way to automatically create `$chats` depend on the numbers on for loop?...

Comment: right now I'm trying what you suggested.. but I can't create it :(